# Теги(ключевые слова статьи), нужно ли ставить nofollow?

Tags: seo

Меня интересует вопрос, нужно ли перекрывать индексацию тегов на странице? Все таки вес перетекает на эту страницу, а если тегов около 20, то это же беда. В поиске выдает поиск по тегам теперь, а самой этой статьи нет. Что думаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Безусловно, любые страницы с результатами поиска, и поиск по тэгу не исключение, нужно закрывать от индексирования. Нет ничего ужаснее чем страница "XYZ не найдено", попавшая в выдачу гугла по запросу XYZ - после десятого такого "нахождения" посетитель просто перестанет обращать на ваш сайт внимание.

Но напоминаю, что для закрытия страницы от индексирования используется noindex, а не nofollow.

Во-первых, высокая связность страниц внутри вашего сайта не вредна а скорее полезна - благодаря ней поисковики быстрее будут находить новые страницы и присваивать им ранг.

Во-вторых, вы никогда не сможете перекрыть через nofollow все ссылки, ведущие на некоторую страницу. Достаточно чтобы любой пользователь опубликовал ссылку на "закрытую" страницу за пределами вашего сайта - и все, Яндекс о "тайной" странице знает. А чтобы о странице узнал Гугл - достаточно зайти на нее через Chrome.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Я не правильно задал вопрос, прошу прощения. Мне именно нужен nofollow, так как не хочу передавать вес страницы на теги, ибо там есть перелинковка на другие посты, на которые нужно передавать вес. А вот теги пускай индексируються хоть и без веса. Проблема заключается в отсутствии самого поста при точном поиске, а теги из поста находяться.

Comment: @dimabuhayov забудьте про "передачу веса"! Просто закройте тэги от индексирования, этого достаточно.